# Access JSON files through API request

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a bunch of JSON files that I would like to grab in my React app through an API request. I know I can read and parse each JSON file, but eventually I would like to host these JSON files on the backend. I'm familiar with having a local server running and using that URL to make a request, but I'm not sure how to serve my JSON files on one server and make my API requests from the server that my React App is running on. Any recommendations or tips on how to start would be great!

Comment: Why do you want to host json files. You could look into dumping json into postgresql database

Comment: Eventually, I would want to dump the JSON files into a database, but I want to test making a GET request to these JSON files.

Comment: what server are you using/what is the rest of your stack looking like?

Comment: I think your comment just lit off a lightbulb. I have my React project running on its own server through a script, but then I also have my folder with my json files in the same project. And I think I can't the json folder in the same directory if my intention is to run both on different servers

Comment: awesome. Yeah. You'll need an endpoint ie a server (hapi, express, other) that will serve the rest requests to your client side react app. Good luck